# Java Sound File Not Playing

Tags: java, windows, class, audio, applet

I have this in a regular class, and not an applet, so I'm not sure if that is the problem or not but here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Platformer
{
   public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
   { try 
      {
          AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip
          (new URL("file://g:/scarface.wav"));
          clip.play();
      }
      catch(MalformedURLException murle)
      {
          System.out.println(murle);
      }
   }


}
```

The audiofile is on my flashdrive in the G drive and not within a folder.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I would consider it a bit strange to utilise an Applet in this way, applets can make special decisions when it comes to looking for resources and have security restrictions each may prevent it from performing, what seems like, simple task. Take a look at [the sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) for alternatives

Comment: The URL must be formed relative to the code base or document base of the applet.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have problems with audio files because I rarely use them, but I had problem accessing files on mounted flash drives. Something to do with the plug and play.

Try having the file on the C: drive. If it works there you know it is something with the G: drive.

One error that often happens to me while accessing flash drives is that I pull them without dismounting them and plug them back and all of a sudden I end up with 2 drives, where only one is a real one, the other is a ghost.

Maybe it can't find the file. Just for debug sake, move the file to the root of the C: drive and use this as the location of the file   `file:///C:/scarface.wav`

Comment: I moved the file to my C: drive, but the sound still didn't play.  With both of them I noticed that the program continued running for the length of the .wav file, but the sound is not heard at all.  Perhaps it is something with java volume?

Comment: Try this AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip
          (new URL("/g:/scarface.wav"));

Comment: I end up with the following error:                  java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /g:/scarface.wav

Comment: Try adding an "clip.stop()"